# Increase threshold for rejected edits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

After re-editing [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811658/computational-complexity-of-fourth-order-butterworth-filter-and-fastica-in-matla) on Stack Overflow after it was rejected with the same changes, the post was accepted. I didn't notice it was rejected it before and applied the same changes. Why doesn't Stack Exchange simply increase the rejection threshold and asking for even more reviews than it did for edits instead?

Here is a screenshot of my post activity.

[image]

From each review, only one person reviewed my change for the rejection and the acceptance. The acceptance was done by the OP of the post in question (pardon the pun).

Comment: perhaps the down voter could comment as suggested by StackExchange?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If click on the [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7796440) link you'll see the reason the edit was rejected:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

By holding your mouse over times in the question and review history that display "1 hour ago" etc you can see the exact timestamp of when things occurred. In this case the OP applied an edit one minute after your suggestion which overwrote it and hence it was rejected by the community user.

They were probably still working on their edit at the time and may not have noticed your edit. It's fairly common when trying to suggest close to when a new question is posted because the OP or other users with enough reputation to directly edit may have quickly spotted similar or other problems and be in the process of doing an edit themselves.

Comment: In this case, would it not make sense to send the edit back to the original editor for them to revise it and see how to resolve the conflict? For instance, it could be put into the inbox as a "Conflicting Edit" entry after StackExchange sends it back to you (it is an IN-box after all). +1 for pointing out the editing conflict.

Comment: I guess that would make it faster to spot the conflict so you could go back and check if another edit was needed, and they are probably rare enough so that the extra messages wouldn't be too annoying. I guess the only downside I can think of is it may be a bit demotivating if someone gets messages a lot of their edits ended up being discarded.

Comment: The reason I point this out is that if 2 people edit the same question, there's going to be conflicts regardless of who reviews it. Better have the original editor to resolve it instead of getting someone else to. Plus usually the editor is one of the participants with an answer so it would be doubly useful. That's okay, I can always click the button on the right labelled achievements to re-motivate myself ;) Joke aside if it's going to be discarded anyways, it might need to be re-done again anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [PeterJ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254150/245360) on the events that happened.

Also, the OP of a post has special privileges when it comes to edits on his/her post: Whenever an edit is suggested, he or she can approve or reject a suggested edit without the intervention of others. This special privilege can be used to approve an edit of someone who was commenting for example, understands the problem, and edits your post. The OP, of all people, know best if an edit should be approved or not.

Comment: Gotcha, but it wasn't the OP who rejected it, it was a moderator. I presume the moderators have similar 1 person say?

Comment: Also is there a way to lock the question? I really don't want to lose rep due to my question not being "favourable" to people

Comment: I can't see a moderator did, but he has super powers :)

Comment: No. You can't lock a question against voting. It will fade away eventually.

Comment: Can you see Community (Star) at the top of this [rejected edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7796440)? I believe the star means they're a mod. Also what do you mean it'll fade away eventually?

Comment: It means it was rejected due to a concurrent edit.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I'm guessing the account is a bot then for the site's backend. And I'm still unsure what you meant by fade away eventually.

Comment: You are correct.